# Android activity life cycle with asynctask

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have been doing some research on activity life cycles and how they free usable space so my application can run smoother.  Its just that I would like to use these methods for one of my activities because when my PDialog launches it takes quite some time for my data to load.  I have been look at my code to see where I can place these method, so when my activity is executing  my asynctask, That will be the only thing I want to be running at that point of time.my code below will clear things up.

```
    public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

         final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
         final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
         final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
         final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
         final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
         final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
         final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
         final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
         final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
         final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

                JSONArray question = null;          
                android.widget.ListView lv;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

        questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 


        new LoadAllData().execute();

            }


        @Override   
        protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
             super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

              HashMap<String, String> item = questionList.get(pos);

              Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
              i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT));
              i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT));
              i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER));
              startActivity(i);

                }     

        class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            private Dialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                ProgressDialog pDialog; 
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                try {
                    Intent in = getIntent();
                    String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                    String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                    String URL = "http://example.com";
                    JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                    JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                    try {

                        JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                        for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                        String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                        String NumAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                        String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                        String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                        //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                        //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                        //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                   map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                                   map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);
                                   map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                                   map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                                   questionList.add(map);


                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    return TAG_QUESTION ;           

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {
                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                            R.layout.listelements,
                            new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                            R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers, });

                    setListAdapter(adapter); 


            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
        }

    }
```

In my previous class I have already put `onStop` to free up some space. But I hope now you can see more of what I mean when I say that I just want to PDialog and my asynctask to be running at that point of time so that my PDialog doesn't slow down the process.

Comment: Still dont get your idea, why does the `PDialog`slow down the process? The processing time depends on `doInBackground` method, the `PDialog` is only to lock the screen while the download happening. If you want to keep track of your download status, please use `onProgressUpdate` and show to users through progress bar. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2652394 My code to dismiss pDialog `if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();` is referring to this `private Dialog pDialog;` So there for what I thought was making my pDialog to run very slowly was never the case. I believe my pDialog was never being dismissed to begin with

Answer (score 0):

For me is not actually clear what is question about. For a reference two important points if some newbee comes here and read.

1. it takes some time list to load because it is long operation. Purpose of AsyncTask is to ***keep UI not blocked***. It's purpose is not to magicaly speed up things to infinity (btw even if it is light speed is a limit).
2. `onStop()` in this code is useless, it does nothing. `super.onStop()` would be called even if you delete completely your overriden `onStop` method because base class ListActivity is extended from Activity which has this method and it will be called. You didn't add anything by just calling `super.onStop()`
3. Just for records `onPreExecuting` and `onPostExecute` are executing on main (UI) thread..`doInBackground` is running in separate thread but Android wrapped everything nice for you so these methods execute on appropriate threads one after another.
4. Seems like you don't know why but your `doInBackground` method needed to return some string so you returned any that you had (`TAG_QUESTION`).. ;) than `onPostExecute` accepted that `String` as parameter but of course you didn't use it. String was required there because you declared `AsyncTask` with `<String,String,String>` not knowning what is that for.

Hopefully some material about [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) can help to someone who landed here